# How to get firestore collection response in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way i can get the response in an Array format when i query in the cloud firestore?
I know two ways but I want to know if there is any other way which is directly linked to that

```
const queryRef = await db.collection('xyz').where('time','==',29).get()
const array = []
queryRef.forEach(doc => {
    array.push(doc.data())
})
```

there is other way also like this way.

```
 const array2 = queryRef.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
```

Is there any way to get the same response without using external javascript methods and if possible how can i count the number of response which is satisfying the queries
like

```
const queryRef = await db.collection('xyz').where('time','==',29).get()
```

I don't know how many documents i get in this query untill i perform or store that in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the code you're showing uses an "external javascript method".  Both the foreach loop and the `map()` you're showing are very standard JavaScript and both equally valid.  In fact, these are the two most common ways that I've seen for consuming Firestore query results.  It's not clear to me why you need something different.

You have a second question here about counting results from a query using `await`:

```
const queryRef = await db.collection('xyz').where('time','==',29).get()
```

That code is misleading because the result from that query is not a reference.  It's a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).  But if you want the number of results from that object, just access the resulting document array:

```
const count = queryRef.docs.length
```

Firestore doesn't offer a way to count documents without making a query.  There are no aggregate functions as in SQL.  If you need a document count without a query, you're going to have to maintain a document count on your own as you add and remove documents to a collection.

Comment: I know but is there any method or way to solve this?

Comment: To solve what?  Please read my answer completely.  If you're looking for a way to count documents as I suggested, I think you should do a web search for that.

Comment: I got your point but using this means i have to use an extra variable I want to write this code in a more efficient way. that's why i asked this question.if possible can you tell me any way regarding my question

Comment: That part is sorted i wanted to ask regarding  my first question

Comment: There's nothing inefficient about what you're doing now.  If you think you have a performance problem, benchmark your code and figure out where exactly the performance problem is before making a change.